# ui:repeat does not work in JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf-2, seam, facelets

In my page, `<ui:repeat>` does not work. `<c:forEach>` is work. I don't know what am I missing? Otherwise, Does not `<ui:repeat>` work JSF 2.0?

mypage.xhtml (it does not work)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                template="/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="toDeleteForm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ui:repeat value="#{DatePick.timeSlot}" var="timeSlot">
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeSlot}" style="font-size:12px;"/><br/>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

mypage.xhtml (it is ok)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                template="/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="toDeleteForm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <c:forEach items="#{DatePick.timeSlot}" var="timeSlot">
                                <h:outputText value="#{timeSlot}" style="font-size:12px;"/>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

DatePick.java

```
@Name("DatePick")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class DatePick {

    public List<String> getTimeSlot() {
        // list form database
        return timeSlot;
    }
}
```

Output will be as below in my page.

```
    01/01/2012
02/01/2012
03/01/2012
04/01/2012
05/01/2012
```

Comment: What's the result you are getting? Is <ui:repeat> printed to your HTML or is an error thrown?

Comment: @w4rumy, I did not get any error. It just does not show my output in UI.

Comment: what do you mean with the "output in UI"? Can you show the HTML output?

Comment: I wonder if it works different with a session scope (ui repeat)

Comment: it should work, can you remove "</br>" or replace it with "<br />"? in the ui:repeat example? it might be a parse error.

Comment: What if you replace `<ui:repeat>` by `<h:dataTable>`? What is that `@Name` and `@Scope` annotation? This isn't recognizeable as standard Java EE 6 annotations. What 3rd party library are you using to manage your beans? What if you just use Java EE 6 standard annotations like JSF `@ManagedBean` or CDI `@Named`?

Comment: @BalusC I use JBoss Seam 2.3.0

Comment: When I run your code in a Seam 2.3 project, the page with ui:repeat generates an error page until the </br> tag is replaced with <br/>.  Then it displays correctly.

Comment: @gebuh, I update <br/>. Actually it does not matter. I add it when I submit this post. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: The pure HTML isn't being processed by the JSF lifecycle - that isn't going to help. Use <h:dataTable> as @BalusC suggests. <c:forEach> is working because that also is ignored by the JSF lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I used Java EE 6 annotations and it worked fine on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 with Mojarra 2.1.6. I did modify your code, but here it is.

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class DatePick implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5061581851476260511L;

    public DatePick() {
    }

    public List<String> getTimeSlot() {
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 3109256773218160485L;

            {
                add("01/1/2012");
                add("02/1/2012");
                add("03/1/2012");
                add("04/1/2012");
                add("05/1/2012");
                add("06/1/2012");
                add("07/1/2012");
                add("08/1/2012");
                add("09/1/2012");
                add("10/1/2012");
                add("11/1/2012");
                add("12/1/2012");
            }
        };
        return dates;
    }
}
```

and here is the page...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="./WEB-INF/templates/main.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <ui:repeat value="#{datePick.timeSlot}" var="timeSlot">
                        <h:outputText value="#{timeSlot}"/><br/>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The result was the expected output. **Note:** I did not start, or end a conversation.

There were some issues with  that were fixed in 2.1 in a couple of different builds. You would need to look at the release notes for a particular build and issues resolved.

**UPDATE**

I posted the complete solution here: [stackoverflow-ui-repeat-example](http://code.bluelotussoftware.com/stackoverflow-uirepeat-example)